# How to improve performance of pushing data to a mutex locked queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization

I have a queue of "jobs" (function pointers and data) pushed onto it from a main thread, which then notifies worker threads to pop the data off and run it.

The functions are pretty basic and look like this:

```
class JobQueue {
public: 
    // usually called by main thread but other threads can use this too
    void push(Job job) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);   // this takes 40% of the thread's time (when NOT sync'ing)
            ready = true;
            queue.emplace_back(job);
        }
        cv.notify_one();   // this also takes another 40% of the thread's time
    }

    // only called by worker threads
    Job pop() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        cv.wait(lock, [&]{return ready;});
        Job job = list.front();
        list.pop_front();
        return job;
    }

private:
    std::list<Job>            queue;
    std::mutex                mutex;
    std::condition_variable   cv;
    bool                      ready;
};
```

But I have a major problem, **`push()` is really slow**. The worker threads outpace the main thread, which in my test adding jobs is all the main thread does.  (The worker threads perform 20 4x4 matrix rotations that feed into eachother and get printed at the end so they're not optimized away)  This seems to get worse with the number of worker threads available too.  If each "Job" is bigger, say 100 matrix operations, this negative goes away and more threads == better, but the Jobs I would give it in practice are much smaller than that.

The hottest calls are the mutex lock and `notify_one()`, which take up 40% of the time each, everything else is negligible it seems.  Also, the mutex lock is rarely waiting, it is nearly always available.

I'm not sure what I should do here, is there an obvious or not-so obvious optimization I can make that will help, or perhaps I have made a mistake?  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

(here are some metrics I took if it might help, they don't count the time it takes to create threads, the pattern is the same even for billions of jobs)

```
Time to calc 2000000 matrice rotations
(20 rotations x 100000 jobs)
threads   0:       149 ms  << no-bool baseline
threads   1:       151 ms  << single threaded w/pool
threads   2:        89 ms
threads   3:       120 ms
threads   4:       216 ms
threads   8:       269 ms
threads  12:       311 ms  << hardware hint
threads  16:       329 ms
threads  24:       332 ms
threads  96:       336 ms
```

[image]

[image]
(all worker threads have the same pattern, green is execution, red is waiting on synchronization)

Comment: Batch up the jobs. Instead of adding one job at a time, add a whole bunch at a time. Use per-worker job queues, and have the main thread, that generates each job, add it to a per-worker job queue. There are many other variations possible, it all depends on the individual circumstances.

Comment: Condition variables are exoensive when there is contention.  Don't `wait` if ready is true when you grab the lock in `pop()`

Comment: @Chad - Oh, I thought it checked the predicate before trying to wait.  I tried adding another check around it but there wasn't any improvement unfortunately.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - I'll try to add a per-worker job queue.  I initially avoided it because it makes joining harder, but it might be worth it in this case.  Batching too

Comment: @AnneQuinn Are you setting ready to false again anywhere ? As you have multiple consumers on your queue, you need to set it to false only when the queue is empty again - in which case you should rather use !queue.empty() as a predicate..

Comment: Use an atomic to increment/decrement position? Assign tasks to thread-specific queues round-robin style?

Comment: @nos - Yeah, I cut out that portion of the logic to keep the code concise, but it sets it to false once the queue is emptied

Comment: 1) Is there any reason why you have to scale up to 96 threads? Why not use a threadpool with same number of threads as you have cores available? 2) How many milliseconds would you expect a job to take? If the jobs are pretty short, it would be better to go into lockfree queues than to use heavy-weight mutex/cv synchronization.

Comment: @HumphreyWinnebago - That's just to see what effect oversubscription had, in practice it would run at whatever hardware hint I can get.  As for the jobs, they're just a few matrix transforms, 20 or so each.  Ideally, the act of adding a job would be a small fraction of time compared with the act of actually performing it (otherwise there's no benefit to multi-threading).  Not sure how lockfree queues would work, but I'll look into it

Comment: Oh I see. I assumed the transforms were for testing purposes but it sounds like that's your actual use-case. Is it always the same transforms? If there are no (or few) conditional branches, you can get a huge boost from vectorized (aka SIMD) operations. Will there be a huge batch of jobs (i.e. is it worth putting on the GPU)? Are you using a library to do the transforms?

Comment: How many suppliers do you have (i.e., threads concurrently adding work to the queue)?

Comment: @davidbak - Usually just one, if I can allow multiple to push jobs that'd be a nice thing to have, but it's not necessary or anything

Comment: @HumphreyWinnebago - Well, it's for draw call proxies mostly.  Basically the Jobs are handling drawing logic, converting objects into chewed up primatives for the render thread, performing culling and other assorted operations along the way.  But I want to keep them general enough that I can use them for other things as well.  The GPU is already saturated with what I'm giving it to draw, any more would likely bottleneck on it

Comment: I agree with the others. Either batch jobs together or just use a single thread. You can get more efficiency from a good library (e.g. GLM, Eigen, MKL, BLAS). Make sure, for the operations you will be using, the library makes full use of your hardware's SIMD operations. OpenMP can take advantage of SIMD as well as automatically manage task distribution (if you DO decide to use multithreading in the end).

Comment: If mutex/cv is still a significant overhead, you can replace mutex locking with some kind of lockfree producer-consumer mechanism, (e.g. A rolling buffer of pointers, each one pointing to a batch of jobs. There are two atomic variables that are incremented as batches are added/completed, one indicating the first job and one indicating the last), but you would still need to batch jobs if you wanted to maximize scalability to additional cores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Do more work in each task.  (Perhaps take more than one current task off the queue each time, but there are many other possibilities.)

Your tasks are (computationally) too small. A 4x4 matrix multiplication is just a few multiplies and adds.  ~60-70 operations.  20 of them done together isn't much more expensive, ~1500 (pipelined) arithmetic operations.  The cost of the thread switch including waking a thread waiting on the cv and then the actual context switch, is likely higher than this - possibly *much* higher.

Also, the cost of the synchronization (the manipulation of the mutex and the cv) is very expensive, especially in the case of contention, especially on a multi-core system where the hardware native synchronization operations are much more expensive than arithmetic (because of cache coherency enforcement between the multiple cores).

This is why you observe that the problem lessens when each task is doing 100 of these matrix operations, increased from 20: The workers were going back to the well for more stuff to do too often, causing contention, when they only had 20 MMs to do ... giving them 100 to do slows them down enough that contention is reduced.

(In a comment you indicate that there is only one supplier, pretty much eliminating that as a source of contention to the queue. But even there, the more tasks than can be enqueued together while under the cv lock the better - up to the limit where it is blocking workers from taking tasks.)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an event handler.

The events are of two types:

- New job arrives
- Worker completes job

The main thread maintains a job queue, accessed only by the main thread ( so no mutex locking )

When a job arrives it is placed on job queue.
When a worker completes a job a job is popped and passed to the worker

You will also need a free worker queue, at startup and when no jobs are available.

You will also need an event handler.  These are tricky, so best to use a well tested library rather than rolling your own.  I use boost::asio